# Jquerymobile: touch event slower in Android than in iOS

Tags: android, ios, google-maps-api-3, jquery-mobile

I created a simple web app with jquerymobile and google maps JS API: http://www.mastercomunicazionestorica.it/geo//botteghestoriche4.html  (the buttons functions are not yet implemented). On iOS (iPhone and Ipad) no problems while panning the map, but when I pan the map on Android touch devices the responsiveness is extremely slow: what could be the reason and how is it possibile to solve the problem?Thanks!
Giac

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that this something that depends on the operating system, but instead, it might be the problem of the phone you are using. It might have low end processor or random access memory which might be the reason behind the slow responsiveness. And just to let you know, the link you gave works perfect on my HTC HD2 with android 2.3.3 :D